# How can I avoid repeating the replacement character when replacing substrings

Tags: java, replace

I have the following string in a database

```
**final test project - test decorations**
```

and I want to replace spaces with dashes (*the `-`character*). This is what I have so far:

```
tit1 = rs.getString("title");
tit1 = tit1.replaceAll("\\s{1}", "-");
```

The outputs looks like this

```
**final-test-project---test-decorations**
  **shadow-of-the-test----test**
```

but i want output like this

```
**final-test-project-test-decorations**
   **shadow-of-the-test-test**
```

How can I make the replacement ignore the single dash surrounded with whitespaces?

Answer (score 5):

You may use the following line

```
tit1 = tit1.replaceAll("[\\s-]+", "-");
```

instead of your call to `replaceAll`. It takes all consecutive spaces together with dashes and replaces them by a single dash.

Comment: but same output i am getting what i mentioned 2nd one  can you clarify on this....

Comment: @user1135693 Can you please state clearly what is the input and what do you expect. This answer corresponds exactly to what you state below "I want output like this". I actually do not understand what you mean by "ignore the single dash".

Comment: i am getting this output "shadow-of-the-test----test" but i want "shadow-of-the-test-test" single - where ever i can get ---,--,---- dashes i want single - .

Comment: thanks howard for early reply see my input is from database **final test project  test decorations**(some where 3or4or5 spaces are there in string) i want output is only 1 char for 3or4 spaces 'final-test-project-test-decorations' like this